# List of Hidden Values in Markup

Tags: asp.net

I have am trying to create a list of hidden items in my markup, this might be a very simple question but I can't see how to do it as you don't really put functional code in markup pages (I know JavaScript).

In MVC I would just do something like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.myListOfItems)
{
   <input type="hidden" id="item_id_ @item.Id" value="@item.Value" />
}
```

And that would create me a list of hidden items that I oculd use.  How can I do this in ASP.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `<% %>` to run your loop :

```
<% foreach (var item in ListOfItems) { %>

 //create your inputs

<% }%>
```

Another option would be to add them from code behind. see [this](http://ganeshmohan.wordpress.com/aspnet-and-c-generate-html-controls-dynamically/)